# Is there a way in R to filter and split a dataframe into new dataframes?

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I have a dataframe with a few hundred of thousand entries and would like to subset the whole dataframe by a few types.

The data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("x12", "x32", "x12", "x123", "x32", "y312", "y312", "z213", "x342", "xs32", "x1f2", "x1r23", "xw32", "y5312", "yf312", "z2z13"), 
date = c("2019-04-01 22:03:12", "2019-01-03 18:03:12", "2019-02-22 23:42:04", "2019-08-01 12:03:42", "2019-03-31 12:53:32", "2019-06-13 09:59:18", "2019-04-01 18:14:52", "2019-07-14 15:02:22",
                     "2019-01-11 12:33:42", "2019-07-17 19:39:28", "2019-05-27 19:44:42", "2019-03-17 15:02:52",
                     "2019-02-22 14:23:22", "2019-05-12 23:79:48", "2019-02-21 12:24:22", "2019-04-12 15:02:32"), 
type = c("blue", "black", "blue", "red", "black", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black", "black", "blue", "black", "red", "red", "red"))

df

      id                date   type
1    x12 2019-04-01 22:03:12   blue
2    x32 2019-01-03 18:03:12  black
3    x12 2019-02-22 23:42:04   blue
4   x123 2019-08-01 12:03:42    red
5    x32 2019-03-31 12:53:32  black
6   y312 2019-06-13 09:59:18 yellow
7   y312 2019-04-01 18:14:52 yellow
8   z213 2019-07-14 15:02:22  green
9   x342 2019-01-11 12:33:42   blue
10  xs32 2019-07-17 19:39:28  black
11  x1f2 2019-05-27 19:44:42  black
12 x1r23 2019-03-17 15:02:52   blue
13  xw32 2019-02-22 14:23:22  black
14 y5312                <NA>    red
15 yf312 2019-02-21 12:24:22    red
16 z2z13 2019-04-12 15:02:32    red
```

I would like to filter out the blue, red and black type and create a own data frame for each type.

After subsetting I would like to filter and mutate some new variables in the new created dataframes like this.

```
df_blue <- df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(type == "blue") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(bluedate == date) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(date == min(date)) 

df_red <- df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(type == "red") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(reddate == date) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(date == min(date))

df_black <- df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(type == "black") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(blackdate == date) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(date == min(date))
```

Because the mutating and filtering is identical except the type filter and the datename, I would like to do it in a loop or apply a function, but I'm not sure how.

I tried a loop, but until now only the subsetting works, but not the mutating:

```
color <- c("blue", "red", "black")

for (i in color){
assign(paste0("df_", i), subset(df, type == i))
}
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
for (i in color){
assign(paste0("df_", i), subset(df, type == i & date == min(date))) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(paste0(i, "date") == date) %>% 
dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
dplyr::filter(date == min(date))
```

}

Is there a way to do is in a loop, using apply or anything that is nicer that i don't need to repeat myself?

Comment: You can do a group by `filter` `df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% group_by(type, id) %>% filter(date == min(date))` instead of creating multiple datasets in the global env

Comment: Oh wow! Why didn't think about this? This is a nice solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
filter df %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
   group_by(type, id) %>%
   filter(date == min(date))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to keep objects in a list instead of creating multiple datasets which are difficult to manage. We can first convert the `date` column to `POSIXct` type, `group_by` `id` and `type` and select the minimum `date` value and use `group_split` to split the data into multiple data frames.

```
library(dplyr)

list1 <- df %>%
           mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %T")) %>%
           group_by(id, type) %>%
           slice(which.min(date)) %>%
           group_split()
list1

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  id    date                type 
#  <chr> <dttm>              <chr>
#1 x12   2019-02-22 23:42:04 blue 

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  id    date                type 
#  <chr> <dttm>              <chr>
#1 x123  2019-08-01 12:03:42 red  

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  id    date                type 
#  <chr> <dttm>              <chr>
#1 x1f2  2019-05-27 19:44:42 black
#.....
```

If you want to access each dataframe, you could do `list1[[1]]`, `list2[[1]]` and so on.

Comment: Ah I see! Thats also a good solution. Haven't thought about it. Thanks a lot!